how to View / Read SMS of a device through web
I am trying to build a web app that have reading and sending SMS through pushbullet devices
pushbullet web app already have these features but i cannot find the correct apis for both of those functions
I found pushbullet library for python that has push_sms function and it is working correctly
as expected but there is no reading or retrieving  for new or the already existing SMSs

you need to share your codes and tries and the errors your encontering.

I have communicated with the colaborator of PushBullet and i was told it was archived and cannot be done
